# Python (Django) createsuperuser not working with docker-compose environment

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently running a project using django in docker. I have a docker-compose file that starts and runs an nginx server, an app server running alpine and a db-server running postgresql. All of these start up like they're supposed to and I can access the blank site on my localhost IP 127.0.0.1:8000.

At the moment there's no models or views or anything, I just want to create the admin user for now.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine                                                      
                                                                     
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1                                               
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1                                        
                                                                     
RUN apk add python3-dev postgresql-client postgresql-dev musl-dev build-base
                                                                     
COPY . /app                                                          
WORKDIR /app                                                         
                                                                     
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                  
                                                                     
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'                                
                                              
services:                                     
  web:                                        
    image: nginx:latest                       
    ports:                                    
      - 8000:8000                             
    volumes:                                  
        - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/         
    networks:                                 
        - webnet                              
    depends_on:                               
        - app                                 
                                              
  app:                                        
    image: bankimage:latest                   
    networks:                                 
      - dbnet                                 
      - webnet                                
    env_file:                                 
      - env                                   
    depends_on:                               
      - db                                    
                                              
  db:                                         
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine               
    volumes:                                  
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/        
      - ./dbscripts/:/dbscripts/              
    networks:                                 
      - dbnet                                 
    env_file:                                 
      - env                                   
                                              
volumes:                                      
  data:                                       
                                              
networks:                                     
  dbnet:                                      
  webnet:
```

I can access the database with `python manage.py exec db`  and I can see all the tables created for django, so I know there's a connection.

Database setup:

`env`

```
POSTGRES_USER=pguser          
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword  
POSTGRES_DB=bankdb            
TZ=Europe/Copenhagen          
PGTZ=Europe/Copenhagen
```

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
         'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
         'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
         'HOST': 'db',
         'PORT': '5432',
```

I am trying to create a superuser so I can access the admin-panel, but for some reason I get some errors when I try to run `python manage.py createsuperuser`

I have deleted and rebuild my images, containers, volumes associated with the db and rerun docker-compose, but to no avail. All I get when I try to create a superuser is these errors:

```
type heTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/2023-1/epsilon_bank/bank_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/name/2023-1/epsilon_bank/bank_project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/name/py-env/epsilonbank/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/name/py-env/epsilonbank/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/name/py-env/epsilonbank/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/name/py-env/epsilonbank/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/name/py-env/epsilonbank/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/name/2023-1/epsilon_bank/bank_project/bank_project/settings.py", line 80, in <module>
    'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
            ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 679, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'POSTGRES_DB'
re
```

I've tried numerous variations of manage.py createsuperuser, prefixing it with docker-compose, adding exec etc, but any command returns the same issues.

I am new to Django in general, but I want to learn. I could be missing the obvious, so bare with me!

Comment: from the logs, it seems the file is not able to fetch your Environment variables. So you dont need to mess with Create super user. Database connection is failed. Just try to get env variables. Share your `settings.py` after removing secrets.